# To what degree does the ACA decrease the average lifespan of young/healthy individuals?

Tags: united-states, affordable-care-act

Correct me if wrong, the ACA requires that:

- People own health insurance
- Health insurers cannot charge their oldest customers more than three times 
     what they charge their youngest customers
- Health insurers cannot decline applications due to applicants' preexisting conditions

It seems plausible that increased premiums for young/healthy individuals and increased opportunities to seek medical services for old/unhealthy individuals would lead to a decrease in retirement funds and a decrease in the quality of medical services for the young/healthy. It's known that both wealth and quality of medical services are correlated with mortality.

To what degree does the ACA decrease the average lifespan of young/healthy individuals? Was this taken into account when enacting the ACA? Would the CBO analyze something like this or would the responsibility fall elsewhere?

Comment: I don't know that anyone knows the answer to this, but the second question (about the CBO) might be better off being it's own question.

Comment: Can you expand on your logic (plausibility) that an increase in young/healthy premiums leads to a decrease in **quality** of medical care for the young/healthy?

Comment: Is this really answerable at this time? Maybe ask again in 50 years when there's data? But even then, I think it's going to be a huge stretch to directly tie universal coverage to lowered lifespans--especially given that the current data globally seems to indicate universal coverage produces longer lifespaces.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that the ACA might not decrease *any* young healthy individual lifespans, (at least not because of averaging premiums); consider:

- Suppose the amount of retirement funds for a young person **was**
  reduced owing to relatively larger premiums reducing their total
  surplus funds available for a retirement nest egg.

  But part of the *need* for a large retirement fund is to pay for
  higher medical expenses in old age.  So today's young person eventually
  grows old, and decades later enjoys relatively *lower* premiums, and
  *lower* medical expenses then.
- Not all young people are islands.

  1. Some young people directly help to    support their parents, and other elder relatives.  Some of that    support necessarily goes into
     medical expenses.  If those medical    expenses are reduced because
     the ACA mandates relatively lower    premiums for the elderly, their
     younger supporters would have *more*    surplus funds available for
     their own retirement nest eggs.
  2. Some young people are themselves supported *by* parents or elder relatives.  If their elders are bankrupted by old age, their young
     dependents may be ruined, or be forced to live day to day, with no
     savings possible.
- As a matter of [public health](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_health), the more persons vaccinated against, and
  promptly treated for, contagious diseases, the fewer vectors such
  diseases and plagues have to attack a given society.  Fewer plagues,
  less stress, less losses of man-hours, *etc*.  Everyone benefits from
  that, however indirectly.

Answer (score -5):

I doubt that anyone has tried to calculate this impact for this reason.  That said though, we do have statistics about the [mortality rate for people aged 15-64](https://thefederalist.com/2017/04/25/running-numbers-mortality-rates-suggests-obamacare-killing-people/) since the Patient Protection & Affordable Care Act (PPACA; colloquially known as Obamacare) passed in 2010.  In 2010, there were between 245 and 246 deaths per 100,000 people.  In 2015, that had increased to be between 253 and 254 deaths per 100,000.  So an increase of about 8 per 100,000 in that five year period.

It has been asserted that the [age-adjusted rates](https://wonder.cdc.gov/controller/saved/D76/D21F561) do not show the same increase.  They also do not show a decrease in the 2010-2015 time period.  Meanwhile, they do show a consistent decrease in the 1999-2010 time period.  It's also worth asking if age-adjustment is the correct thing to do.  It's not the 55-64 age group that has the highest increase in mortality, but the 25-34 group.  Rather than using the 2000 weights, like WONDER does, it would be interesting to see 2010 or 2015 weights.

An alternative explanation from the [Wall Street Journal](https://www.wsj.com/articles/does-medicaid-spur-opioid-abuse-1506289279):

> Data from the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention show that overdose deaths per capita rose twice as much on average between 2013 and 2015 in states that expanded Medicaid than those that didn’t—for example, 205% in North Dakota, which expanded Medicaid, vs. 18% in South Dakota, which didn’t. . . .  Between 2010 and 2013, overdose deaths rose by 28% in Ohio and 36% in Wisconsin. Between 2013 and 2015, they climbed 39% in Ohio, which expanded Medicaid, but only 2% in Wisconsin, which did not.

The working hypothesis is that Medicaid expansion makes it easier for people to become addicted to opioids (mechanism unknown), so states that expanded Medicaid have seen an increase in deaths from overdose.

This change could also be unrelated to PPACA.  We can only guess that the correlation is indicative of causation.  It might instead be just chance.

The Congressional Budget Office (CBO) could try to estimate the impact you mention.  It's unclear how accurate they would be.  Note that by their estimates, PPACA should be decreasing mortality, not increasing it.  However, if you want them to take a shot at it, consider writing letters to your members of Congress (your Representative and two Senators).  Members of Congress can ask the CBO to score things.  Don't expect a lot though.  The most likely response is a form letter.

Comment: The Federalist article you link to uses raw mortality rates, rather than age-adjusted mortality rates. The increase in mortality rate they cite (for the 15-64 age bracket, excluding drug+ alcohol causes) can be explained by the aging of the population; the trend disappears in the age-adjusted rates.

Comment: @ff524  Please provide a link to the alleged age-adjusted rates.  Or better yet, an answer that includes an equivalent graph.

Comment: The first paragraph seems to imply causation, which seems to be a ridiculous leap given all the other variables--not to mention the incredibly small slice of time we're talking about. The second anecdote, as you state "might instead be just chance" which is correct, though not sure how that helps answer the question.

Comment: @Brythan Crude and age-adjusted mortality rates for the 15-64 age bracket, excluding external causes (as per the Federalist article): [via wonder.cdc.gov](https://wonder.cdc.gov/controller/saved/D76/D21F561). The age-adjusted rate is flat from 2010-2015. You can click on the "Chart" tab to get a graph.

Comment: I won't be writing my own answer based on that chart, because I don't believe looking at mortality rates in isolation yields useful information about the effect of ACA. There are many other factors occurring simultaneously that affect mortality rate (aging of the population is only one of them), and so an off-the-cuff answer is likely to be very problematic.